# Subtraction and division of columns on a pandas groupby object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas DataFrame:

```
  Name  Col_1  Col_2 Col_3 
0     A    3     5    5
1     B    1     6    7
2     C    3     7    4
3     D    5     8    3
```

I need to create a Series object with the values of (Col_1-Col_2)/Col_3 using groupby, so basically this:

```
Name
A   (3-5)/5
B   (1-6)/7
C   (3-7)/4
D   (5-8)/3
```

Repeated names are a possiblty, hence the groupby usage. for example:

```
  Name  Col_1  Col_2 Col_3 
0     A    3     5    5
1     B    1     6    7
2     B    3     6    7
```

The expected result:

```
Name
A   (3-5)/5
B   ((1+3)-6)/7
```

I Created a groupby object:

```
df.groupby['Name']
```

but it seems like no groupby method fits the bill for what I'm trying to do. How can I tackle this matter?

Comment: How your formula should look if there are 2 rows for the same `Name`?

Comment: It's not clear from your question why you need to use a `groupby` at all, is there more data with repeated names that you haven't represented?

Comment: Then the formula should be (n*Col_1-Col_2)/Col_3. N is the amount of rows with the same name. as for 2:  (2*Col_1-Col_2)/Col_3. @GuruStron

Comment: @G.Anderson You are correct, repeated names is a possibility

Comment: Then please update the example to illustrate that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
g = df.groupby('Name')

out = (g['Col_1'].sum()-g['Col_2'].first()).div(g['Col_3'].first())
```

Or:

```
(df.groupby('Name')
   .apply(lambda g: (g['Col_1'].sum()-g['Col_2'].iloc[0])/g['Col_3'].iloc[0])
)
```

Output:

```
Name
A   -0.400000
B   -0.285714
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. haven't thought about using `first()` like that.